# Skip first image on Cycle Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery cycle. That's my JS:

```
$(".page-social-media .works_gallery .slider_cycle").each(function(){
    var id_nr = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).cycle({ 
        fx:    'scrollHorz',
        speed:  500,
        timeout: 0, 
        next:   '#next_' + id_nr, 
        prev:   '#prev_' + id_nr,
    });
});
```

Used startingSlide option but scrollHorz effect crashed and show first image on the last. How can I skip first image on my gallery?

UPDATE:

My HTML structur is dynamic. Like this:

```
<ul class="slider_cycle">
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image" alt="placeholder+image" rel="160"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image" alt="placeholder+image" rel="160"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image" alt="placeholder+image" rel="160"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x600/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image" alt="placeholder+image" rel="160"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: need to see your html related to this in order to work it out, could you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

If the first image is always there, you should be able to do as follows:

```
$(".page-social-media .works_gallery .slider_cycle").each(function(){
    var id_nr = $(this).attr('rel');
    if ($(this).is(':first-child') == false){
        $("#" + id_nr).cycle({ 
        fx:    'scrollHorz',
        speed:  500,
        timeout: 0, 
        next:   '#next_' + id_nr, 
        prev:   '#prev_' + id_nr,
    });
   } else{
   $(this).style('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

that way, if the element is the first child - the top picture, it would set display to none, and otherwise it would cycle as normal, but it depends on the format of the html - does the first image ever get taken away, etc.

Comment: could you post your html then or put up a jsfiddle, so i can check it out?

Comment: could you put your working code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and i will adjust it so that the first image it skipped?